# What kind of HTML element is this? quotes?

Tags: html, dom, text, nodes

I'm checking out the HTML rendering of a page: http://gothamist.com/2010/07/18/wikileaks_founder_no-show_at_nyc_ha.php

if you look at this image you can see when I look at the DOM there are odd character breaks with quotes by  " As a commenter "

http://img153.imageshack.us/f/screenshot20100730at840.png/

Any idea what those are and how I'd strip them out of the DOM to have clean, continuous text?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just how WebKit inspector denotes a [TextNode](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1312295772)

You are seeing more than one textnode surround anchor tags.

If you dump `childNodes` for that div, it looks like this:

```
0: Text
1: HTMLParagraphElement
2: HTMLDivElement
3: Text
4: Text
5: HTMLAnchorElement
6: Text
7: HTMLAnchorElement
8: Text
9: HTMLParagraphElement
10: Text
11: HTMLParagraphElement
12: Text
13: HTMLParagraphElement
14: Text
```

In side the element inspector, those nodes marked as `Text` will be surrounded with quotes. This is just a feature of the element inspector.

> Any idea what those are and how I'd strip them out of the DOM to have clean, continuous text?

Some browsers support `innerText`

For example, run this on that site:

`document.querySelector('.asset-body').innerText`

Answer (score 0):

Those aren't really elements, but text nodes, as they should be. HTML elements contain text nodes.

```
<p>text</p>
```

The `paragraph` element doesn't hold an element, it holds a text node.

One thing I noticed, though, is that you have invalid markup and due to this, the DOM tree within Firefox is inconsistent with Chrome.

That text node for "As a commentor" should be a child of the paragraph, but the invalidness of the `span` ( owned by the paragraph ) containing the `div` in Chrome is making it close the `p` so the text node becomes a sibling. As the HTML parsers creates the tree, it reaches the `<div>` and realizes that it's already within a `p` and `span` and a `span` can't contain a `div` so it closes the `p` and creates a new element, the `div`.

Firefox's DOM tree is lenient and actually allows the nesting to go on. This is the cause of the inconsistency of the placement of the text node which you're referring to.

Basically you have this:

```
<p><span><div>blah</div></span>As a commentor</p>
```

Chrome turns it into

```
<p><span></span></p><div>blah</div>As a commentor
```

Firefox lets it get away with it

```
<p><span><div>blah</div></span>As a commentor</p>
```

Solution: validate your HTML and don't let the `span` contain the `div`:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://gothamist.com/2010/07/18/wikileaks_founder_no-show_at_nyc_ha.php&charset=(detect+automatically)&doctype=Inline&group=0

After you properly mark it up, you'll see that the text node should live inside the `p`.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably your browser. No such thing in FireBug.